# How to change width of facebook login button on web?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering a FB Login button as follows below.  I am trying to get the button to render full width on breakpoints below 768px but the width doesn't change via CSS or javascript to adjust the `data-width` attribute.  According to their docs ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/ ) , the max width is 400px but I know I've seen full screen width buttons before.  Any idea on how I can accomplish this?

```
<div class="fb-login-button" 
    data-width="200px" 
    data-scope="email" 
    data-max-rows="1"  
    data-size="large" 
    data-button-type="continue_with" 
   data-show-faces="false" 
   data-auto-logout-link="true" 
    data-use-continue-as="false" 
   data-onlogin="window.checkLoginState()">
```

EDIT:  Adding rendered markup:

```
<div id="fb-button">
  <div class="fb-login-button fb_iframe_widget" data-width="200px" data-scope="email" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="false" data-onlogin="window.checkLoginState()" login_text="" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" fb-iframe-plugin-query="app_id=203191490405831&amp;auto_logout_link=true&amp;button_type=continue_with&amp;container_width=0&amp;locale=en_US&amp;max_rows=1&amp;scope=email&amp;sdk=joey&amp;show_faces=false&amp;size=large&amp;use_continue_as=false&amp;width=200px">
    <span style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 240px; height: 40px;">
      <iframe name="f28cb7614377564" height="1000px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" allow="encrypted-media" title="fb:login_button Facebook Social Plugin" src="https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/plugins/login_button.php?app_id=203191490405831&amp;auto_logout_link=true&amp;button_type=continue_with&amp;channel=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FafATJJjxKE6.js%3Fversion%3D43%23cb%3Df3b80f280703dbc%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8000%252Ff1ed62ab87a02c4%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;container_width=0&amp;locale=en_US&amp;max_rows=1&amp;scope=email&amp;sdk=joey&amp;show_faces=false&amp;size=large&amp;use_continue_as=false&amp;width=200px" style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 240px; height: 40px;" class=""></iframe>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `data-width` is processed by the FB script and actual CSS is applied upon init. You need to use your browser's document inspector and see what CSS needs to be overridden.

Comment: Not uncommon for people to have their own button without that script also

Comment: Maybe post the resulting HTML snippet so we can have a look-see. I can't find a live demo of FB login.

Comment: @isherwood I have done it in the CSS but their script keeps reverting it back

Comment: We can't help unless you show some markup. CSS can't be "changed back". It can only be overridden, and that's up to you to make happen. Show the rendered markup.

Comment: @isherwood added rendered markup up above

Comment: And which element are you trying to style? You can't usually access elements inside an iframe from another domain.